# Eager loading returning ID instead of model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eager

I have an issue with Eager Loading using the below code.

Issue is with the Status model

```
$ticket = Ticket::where('id', $id)->with(['customer', 'status', 'notes' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
}])->first();
```

If I do,

```
return response()->json($ticket);
```

I get the expected response, all OK

```
{"id":1,"customer_id":10001,"ztk_ticket_no":"ZTK0000001","status":{"id":1,"value":"Open","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20","updated_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20"},"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20","updated_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20","customer":{"id":1,"customer_id":10001,"title":"Test Company","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20","updated_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20"},"notes":[{"id":1,"ticket_id":1,"note":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ","status":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20","updated_at":"2016-02-13 01:36:20"}]}
```

But if I do

```
return response()->json($ticket->status);
```

I get the id of the status, not the Model

```
1
```

**Status Model:**

```
class Status extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'statuses';
}
```

**Ticket Model:**

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public function status() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Status', 'id', 'status');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: $ticket->status()->get();

Comment: Oh that works, thanks.

Any idea why I have to do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your relationship definition, it looks like your `Ticket` model has a field named `status`. If you have a field name on your model with the same name as one of your relationship methods, when you do `$ticket->status`, you are going to get the value of field, not the related object.

So, based on what I can see, it looks like your `tickets.status` field is a foreign key to the `statuses` table. If this is the case, then there are a few issues.

First, your `status` field should be renamed to `status_id`. This will help remove the ambiguity between the field name and the related object.

Second, since your Ticket model contains the foreign key, it is on the `belongsTo` side of the relationship. It may sound a little weird, but a `Status` can have many `Tickets`, but a `Ticket` belongs to a `Status`. So, you need to change your `status()` relationship from `hasOne` to `belongsTo`.

If you rename the `status` field to `status_id`, you can change your method to this:

```
public function status() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
}
```

With this, you access the id field with `$ticket->status_id`, and the related `Status` object with `$ticket->status`.

If you can't change your `status` field, then it would be a good idea to rename your `status()` relationship method, so your method should look something like this:

```
// relationship method renamed
public function relatedStatus() {
    // second parameter required since foreign key does not conform to Laravel conventions
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Status', 'status');
}
```

With this, you access the id field with `$ticket->status`, and the related status object with `$ticket->relatedStatus`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
$ticket->status()->get();
```

This would return the object.

```
 $ticket->status;
```

This one will only return the raw id.

Comment: Is this because I have the column name the same as the model? status?

Comment: No, what you've called is just the model id by default. In order to get the model object as a collection, you call a get function on the relation.

Comment: How come it works if I call $ticket->customer, I get the Model then?

Comment: @JilsonThomas `$ticket->status` would only return the raw id if the `Ticket` model had a field named `status`, in addition to a relationship named `status()`.